# Reverse proxy nodejs on nginx with prerender enabled

Tags: nginx, configuration, reverse-proxy, node.js

I would like to run NodeJS with express web server in a combination of prerender, inside nginx.

What I have so far is a stable configuration for reverse proxy, which works fine - there is also a custom 502 page and let's encrypt certificate.

What I would like to do is put prerender in this picture. I have tried [this](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802) configuration, but it conflicts with my reverse proxy.

My current nginx config, which works fine:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "origin-when-cross-origin" always;
    }
    error_page 502 /index.html;
    location /index.html {
        root /var/www/subdomains/maintenance;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, I have managed to find a configuration which is suitable for me. I have used the [solution posted by David Whitaker](https://medium.com/@damwhitaker/using-aws-ec2-nginx-and-prerender-io-as-a-proxy-for-a-single-page-app-2c3769689060).

Using prerender.io as a local service, along the NodeJS website works like a charm. Hope this helps for anyone with the same issue.